# Android Issue on some devices

Tags: android, device, inetaddress

I want to use the following code for my application:

```
InetAddress inetAddress;
try {
        inetAddress = InetAddress.getByName(hostname);
} catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        return -1;
}
```

It works well on most of the devices I've tested but on the Nexus S Europe and a Huawei device, it throws an exception.

> cannot establish route for 192.168.010.200: unkown host

I've already tried to fix it using the following code in my Application class, but without success:

```
StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitNetwork().build();
StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
```

I've also tried to use AsyncTask but I got the same error. Here is the code I used:

```
private int mInetAddr = -1;
private boolean mInetAck = false; // Acknowledgement

private class AsyncInetAddress extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void>
{
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... hostname)
    {
        InetAddress inetAddress;
        try
        {
            inetAddress = InetAddress.getByName(hostname[0]);
        }
        catch (UnknownHostException e)
        {
            mInetAddr = -1;
            return null;
        }

        byte[] addrBytes;
        int addr;
        addrBytes = inetAddress.getAddress();
        addr = ((addrBytes[3] & 0xff) << 24)
                | ((addrBytes[2] & 0xff) << 16)
                | ((addrBytes[1] & 0xff) << 8)
                | (addrBytes[0] & 0xff);
        mInetAddr = addr;
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result)
    {
        mInetAck = true; // Acknowledgement
    }
}
```

Do you have any idea on how I could fix that ?

Thanks.

**Edit: I've tried on some other devices, problem looks to be present only on version 4.0.* . Works great on 2.* , 3.* and 4.1+.**

Now the problem is located at that line:

```
 if (!connMgr.requestRouteToHost(2, inetAddr))
```

Where `inetAddr = -938825536`. The first param is the MMS type. The condition is always true under a device running 4.0.3 or 4.0.4.

Comment: Do you have the exception that was thrown?  If so, post the log

Comment: Which exception do you get?

Comment: I've edited my post with the exception.

Comment: exception suggests that this device has problems with connection. IP 192.168.10.200 usually means local network. So make sure that both devices are connected to network in same way GSM/WiFi or that VPN is configured.

Comment: All my devices are all conected. That's why it looks weird.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved.
It can't find the route to IP while the wifi is enabled. Simplest way is to disable wifi, do your stuff and then enable wifi.

Here is the code I used:

```
// Disable wifi if it's active
WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
if (wifiManager.isWifiEnabled())
{
      mWasWifiActive = true;
      wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(false);
      Log.e(TAG, "Wifi was enabled, now Off.");
}

// Do stuff here

// Re-enable wifi if it was active before routing
if (mWasWifiActive)
{
       WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
       wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(true);
       Log.e(TAG, "Wifi is back online.");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

At first, what's the specific error that you get?
It is possible that it isn't the problem of the device, but the Android version your are running.

and try to change this:

```
StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitNetwork().build();
StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
```

to:

```
StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
 StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll test it ASAP. I've updated my post with the returned exception.

Comment: i've tried to use your code but it throws the same exception. Any Idea?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) to make your request.

> AsyncTask enables proper and easy use of the UI thread. This class
>   allows to perform background operations and publish results on the UI
>   thread without having to manipulate threads and/or handlers.

Comment: Thanks but why does it work on some devices and not on others ? This problem is really weird.

Comment: it depends on the Android version,recents versions don't let UI Thread do network stuff.

Comment: As Vince sayed, new Android versions do not let you make network requests and works in the MainThread (like the activity or Service). AsyncTask is the best way do to that. If works, mark the question to sinalize.

Comment: Android implemented this from 3.0 and higher.

Comment: I'm going to test a piece of code that implements AsyncTask. I'll give you the results asap.

Comment: I've tried to use it but it gives me the same error. Check my first post to see the code I used. Any other idea ?

Comment: Exception returned is the same: `Unable to resolve host "192.168.010.200": No address associated with hostname`

Comment: I think that is a problem with your code. Check in your AsyncTask if you are receiving the certain parameter in `hostname[0]`

Comment: Log your parameter `String hostName = hostname[0]; Log.d(TAG, hostName);` check it

Comment: @Vodemki ? Give us feedback

Comment: I've been able to make it work on a 4.0.3 device setting up a new APN. I've also changed the `mInetAddr` value with a homemade converter whereas the use of `inetAddress.getAddress()`. I'm still trying to make it work on all devices. Without success for the moment.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I've found so far is the following:

```
public static int lookupHost(String hostname) {
    // Hostname is to be `XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX` or `XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:XXXX`
    hostname = hostname.substring(0, hostname.indexOf(":") > 0 ? hostname.indexOf(":") : hostname.length());
    String result = "";
    String[] array = hostname.split("\\.");
    if (array.length != 4) return -1;

    int[] hexArray = new int[] {0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0};
    hexArray[0] = Integer.parseInt(array[0]) / 16;
    hexArray[1] = Integer.parseInt(array[0]) % 16;
    hexArray[2] = Integer.parseInt(array[1]) / 16;
    hexArray[3] = Integer.parseInt(array[1]) % 16;
    hexArray[4] = Integer.parseInt(array[2]) / 16;
    hexArray[5] = Integer.parseInt(array[2]) % 16;
    hexArray[6] = Integer.parseInt(array[3]) / 16;
    hexArray[7] = Integer.parseInt(array[3]) % 16;

    for (int i=0; i<8; i++)
    {
        result += Integer.toHexString( hexArray[i] );
    }

    return (new Long( Long.parseLong(result, 16) )).intValue();
}
```

It looks to be working on most devices I've tested.